# Solving repetitive composite primary keys in composite entity

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a composite/bridge entity between two different entities:

```
CARDS:
    CARD_ID; [Primary Key]
    // Other attributes

BRIDGE_ENTITY:
    CARD_ID; [Primary & Foreign Key]
    MACHINE_ID; [Primary & Foreign Key]
    // Other attributes

MACHINES:
    MACHINE_ID; [Primary Key]
    // Other attributes
```

Any card registered in the system can be used to access many machines, and vice versa. This is a common many-to-many relationship.

I understand that composite keys cannot have repeating values. But, there is a possibility in my database design that the composite keys in the database design **will** have different values that **repeat** multiple times. How do I modify the attributes in such a way that both `CARD_ID` and `MACHINE_ID` can have the same or different values across multiple rows without causing a problem? Would adding a new primary key towards the bridge entity called `LOG_ID` (unique ID) be possible?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're wanting. From what you've shown above, the `bridge` table is permitted to have multiple rows with the same `card_id` and multiple rows with the same `machine_id`. What it can't have is multiple rows with the same `(card_id, machine_id)` combination. Now are you saying you *want* to have multiple rows with the same `(card_id, machine_id)`?

Comment: @karmakaze Yes, you're correct. Is it correct in my understanding that composite keys do not allow for something like that to work?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting multiple associations between one `CARD_ID` and one `MACHINE_ID`? Whatever that reason is, you can put in a third column of the `bridge` table and also make it part of the primary key so that you can have (CARD_ID, MACHINE_ID, reason) which is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The middle table `bridge_entity` has no restriction on duplicates.  If you want to allow each pair to appear only once, then you want a unique constraint/index (or primary key declaration):

```
alter table bridge_entity add constraint unq_bridge_entity_card_id_machine_id
    unique (card_id, machine_id);
```

Then each *pair* can only appear once -- which is typically what you want.  If you want to allow  duplicates, simply do not declare such a constraint and duplicates will be allowed.